# Generating Custom Object from ArrayList in C# at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, functional-programming

I have the following content stored in ArrayList as pure string each line represents the value of an item in the list , is there a way to generate a dynamic object in the following style :
[left operand is the property] = 
[right operand is the value of that property]

```
object.data.details[1].tid=711
object.data.details[1].type="ongoing"
object.data.details[1].attach="node1"
object.data.details[1].flowing[1].comid="component1"
object.data.details[1].flowing[1].system-usage.RAM="12%"
object.data.details[1].flowing[1].system-usage.CPU="3%"
object.data.details[1].flowing[1].system-usage.Pages=3
object.data.details[1].flowing[2].comid="component2"
object.data.details[1].flowing[2].system-usage.RAM="9%"
object.data.details[1].flowing[2].system-usage.CPU="2%"
object.data.details[1].flowing[2].system-usage.Pages=1
object.data.details[1].flowing[3].comid="component3"
object.data.details[1].flowing[3].system-usage.RAM="7%"
object.data.details[1].flowing[3].system-usage.CPU="7%"
object.data.details[1].flowing[3].system-usage.Pages=5
object.data.details[2].tid=712
object.data.details[2].type="ongoing"
object.data.details[2].attach="node2"
object.data.details[2].flowing[1].comid="component1"
object.data.details[2].flowing[1].system-usage.RAM="12%"
object.data.details[2].flowing[1].system-usage.CPU="3%"
object.data.details[2].flowing[1].system-usage.Pages=3
object.data.details[2].flowing[2].comid="component2"
object.data.details[2].flowing[2].system-usage.RAM="9%"
object.data.details[2].flowing[2].system-usage.CPU="2%"
object.data.details[2].flowing[2].system-usage.Pages=1
object.data.details[2].flowing[3].comid="component3"
object.data.details[2].flowing[3].system-usage.RAM="7%"
object.data.details[2].flowing[3].system-usage.CPU="7%"
object.data.details[2].flowing[3].system-usage.Pages=5
object.data.details[3].tid=713
object.data.details[3].type="ongoing"
object.data.details[3].attach="node2"
object.data.details[3].flowing[1].comid="component1"
object.data.details[3].flowing[1].system-usage.RAM="12%"
object.data.details[3].flowing[1].system-usage.CPU="3%"
object.data.details[3].flowing[1].system-usage.Pages=3
object.data.details[3].flowing[2].comid="component2"
object.data.details[3].flowing[2].system-usage.RAM="9%"
object.data.details[3].flowing[2].system-usage.CPU="2%"
object.data.details[3].flowing[2].system-usage.Pages=1
object.data.details[3].flowing[3].comid="component3"
object.data.details[3].flowing[3].system-usage.RAM="7%"
object.data.details[3].flowing[3].system-usage.CPU="7%"
object.data.details[3].flowing[3].system-usage.Pages=5
```

I wish to have an object with the following structure :

```
object.data.details[i].flowing[j].comid="component1"
if i=j=1
object.data.details[i].flowing[j].system-usage.RAM="9%"
if i=1 and j=2
```

in other words I need to generate a dynamic object that can have an arraylist as a properties list just like when we can access any value displayed in asp.net gridview by using :

```
gridview1.rows[i].someproperty[j].value = "something"
```

I tried to use ExpandoObject but failed also I tried with reflection but it consumes alot of memory if I generate ~1K objects in the same thread.

Comment: Yes, "there is a way to generate a dynamic object in the following style", but it somewhat too broad... Side note: using JSON would make you life much easier...

Comment: The funny thing is that ; this list is actually generated from JSON Object but with custom processor I built so that I can have the result in the way it was posted with the question. @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: and please notice that the structure is not fixed otherwise I could built a class to serialize these string values to :(

Comment: @HassanAlrehamy - I've deleted my answer since it didn't seem to be what you need, could I suggest maybe giving a bit more detail on the problem as at the moment it's not entirely clear what you need; you seem to be saying that you want to take some JSON, transform it, turn it into a bunch of strings, and then turn those strings back into a dynamic object. Which imho doesn't make much sense - maybe if you could clarify what this custom transformation process is and why you can't just transform one dynamic object into another, it might make more sense :)

Comment: @StephenByrne - bro just forget about json and transformation , if you have such data as displayed above , can you or can you not generate a dynamic object on the fly ? this is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I figured out how to do that and just in case someone who would face this problem here is the solution :

1. you have to tokenize each line using dot(.) and pointer to keep track of the index, you should use pointer with ref keyword in order to jump over the SQUARED_OPEN and SQUARED_CLOSED chars as well as the index in between
2. you will need to have the following object

   ```
   ExpandoObject expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
   IDictionary objects = expandoObject;
   ```
3. you need to build a recursive method that is able to add the first level tokenized string (the first token) as dictionary key and its value is expando object.
4. Add the remaining string in each line as value for the expando
5. Tokenize the remaining string which is already stored as expando object then repeat 3,4

and thats all. you will have an expando object that will allow you to access any value by chaining the properties for example :

```
<pre>
var x = data.details[1].flowing[2].system_usage.Pages;
</pre>
```